# Update Command and C#

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I am updating the dataset row with new data from textboxes, then trying to update it to my database. I keep getting this error:

> Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

How can I fix this error?

Here's my code:

```
protected void Save_Butt_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection( "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/PizzaOrders.mdb;Persist Security Info=True" );
    //set up connection string
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [title], [gname], [sname], [address], [suburb], [postcode], [dayphone], [email] FROM [users] WHERE ([username] = @username)", connect);
    OleDbParameter param0 = new OleDbParameter("@username", OleDbType.VarChar);

    param0.Value = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    command.Parameters.Add(param0);

    connect.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet dset = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(dset);

    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["title"] = Title_DDL.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["gname"] = Fname_txt.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sname"] = LN_txt.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["address"] = Address_txt.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["suburb"] = suburb_txt.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["postcode"] = Postcode_txt.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dayphone"] = Phone_txt.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["email"] = Email_txt.Text;

    da.Update(dset);
}
```

Comment: DataAdapter doens't generate the SQL commands to manipulate your database. You have to use a CommandBuilder to generate those commands: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Better tutorial: http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataadapter/commandbuilder-sqlserver.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection( "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/PizzaOrders.mdb;Persist Security Info=True" );

    connect.Open();
    //set up connection string
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID], [title], [gname], [sname], [address], [suburb], [postcode], [dayphone], [email] FROM [users] WHERE ([username] = @username)", connect);
    OleDbParameter param0 = new OleDbParameter("@username", OleDbType.VarChar);

    param0.Value = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    command.Parameters.Add(param0);



    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet dset = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(dset);

    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["title"] = Title_DDL.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["gname"] = Fname_txt.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sname"] = LN_txt.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["address"] = Address_txt.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["suburb"] = suburb_txt.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["postcode"] = Postcode_txt.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dayphone"] = Phone_txt.Text;
    dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["email"] = Email_txt.Text;

    OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(ad);
            builder.QuotePrefix = "[";
            builder.QuoteSuffix = "]";

    da.Update(dset);

    connect.Close();
```

The exception means that you are trying to update the table without the primary key, because of that I add the field [ÏD] in your OleDbCommand. If other field is your primary key change ID with the primary key.
Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

Comment: @user3684557 try it like this ?

Comment: @user3684557 i told you many times that you should add ID in the select clause. In your example it is not added, do you doing this in your code ?

Comment: "username" is my primary ID in the "user" table of my database.

Comment: the exception is the same ?

Comment: There is no error now. But there has been no change to my data base.

Comment: @user3684557 use debug !

Answer (score 2):

Use an [`OleDbcommandBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate the `UpdateCommnand`:

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
```

But you'll need to include the primary key in the `SELECT` command so the update command which rows to update.

Comment: Now I get... "OleDbCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size."

Comment: So set the size of your `@username` parameter to the size of the `username` column.

Comment: OleDbParameter param0 = new OleDbParameter("@username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255); Right? Now I don't get any errors, but the data is not being updated in the db.

Comment: Did you add the table's primary key to your SELECT statement?

Comment: Note that you could also write the `UpdateStatement` yourself and just set it on the `DataAdapter`.  But you'll still need a primary key to know which row to update.

Comment: Yes, OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [username], [title], [gname], [sname], [address], [suburb], [postcode], [dayphone], [email] FROM [users] WHERE ([username] = @username)", connect);

Answer (score 0):

So I have worked out what the issue was... after an hour I figured out that the page was being reloaded before the button click event runs. Thus the page would update the screen with unmodified text from the DB, then when it tried to do an update on the rows... it found none of the fields were changed, so it didn't modify the data.

URRRGH! So frustrating... I knew it would be a simple issue... I fixed the page by placing a "get details" button on the page, so the page_load event would not override user input. *sigh*